# Conditional click event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the count less than -2, the prev button can be clicked as well. I want the prev button not worked if the count less than -2 and so for the next if the count is 1 :

What I've tried but no chance :

**HTML :**

```
  <a href="javascript:" id="prev">prev</a>
  <a href="javascript:" id="next">next</a>
```

**JS :**

```
  $(function() {
    var $prev = $('#prev'),
        $next = $('#next'),
        count = -1;

    function prev() {
      $prev.click(function(){
        count--;
        console.log(count);
      });
    }

    function next() {
      $next.click(function(){
        count++;
        console.log(count);
      });
    }

    if (count > -2) {
      prev();
    } else if (count < 1) {
      next();
    }

  });
```

Here is the result when I click the prev button, and the next button is not worked.please tell me how to make it useful.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please describe your problem.

Comment: Move your click handlers out of the functions. Some description of what you are trying to achieve is required too. Simply saying 'it doesn't work' helps no one.

Comment: why downvoted? the question is right, whats wrong with you people, because you already have background in programming your acting very proud now, not thinking that you also came from that level

Comment: @Sherlock it's downvoted because the OP hasn't stated what he's trying to achieve. We're not all detectives ;)

Comment: @diiN_ `here is the result when i click the prev button, and the next button is not worked.please tell me how to make it useful.` please learn to read

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan he stated it `here is the result when i click the prev button, and the next button is not worked.please tell me how to make it useful.`

Comment: Ok, so what should the `next` button do when it works? Does the OP mean that the handler isn't being run, or that `count` isn't being executed? Or that he's getting an error?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan increment the counter, Just give the guy at least the chance his starting up

Comment: You don't bind next click, read again your logic: `if (count > -2) {
      prev();
    } else if (count < 1) {
      next();
    }`  and you set `count = -1;` so first if block is run and not second one...

Comment: @diiN_ what i want do is when the count > -2, the prev button can work only, but i found the prev button work all the time

Comment: Article is right https://pinoniq.svbtle.com/stackoverflow-is-dead

Comment: So the Q is closed, but the answere is easy. You need to init your event click. Simple way, is to call the function next() and prev() after your if/elseif statement.

Comment: @lifeng1893 But this snippet is called only on document ready... Instead bind both events and check value of `count` inside handlers

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `next()` or `prev()` you will attach new click event to the buttons, you don't need to add those functions just attach event one time, check the example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  var $prev = $('#prev'),
      $next = $('#next'),
      count = -1;

  $prev.click(function(){
    if (count > -2) {
      count--;
      console.log(count);
    }
  });

  $next.click(function(){
    if (count < 1) {
      count++;
      console.log(count);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:" id="prev">prev</a>
<a href="javascript:" id="next">next</a>
```

Comment: See if someone provides an answer, so the question is right.

Comment: @Sherlock Do we know this answer is correct?  Is this actually what the OP is trying to achieve or did they actually only want to bind the events only when the count is between -2 and 1?   We actually don't know and this answer is a guess at best as the OP has not included **a clear problem statement**

Comment: @Sherlock But i think OP doesn't want count to be less than -2 and more than 1. The question is unclear but it is what suggests his posted code

Comment: when the count less than -2, the prev button can be clicked as well. i want the prev button not worked if the count less than -2

Comment: Updated my answer @lifeng1893, try to update you question to be more clear..